# How to show only US country in checkout dropdown and admin orders side display all countries

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, magento2.4

How to show US country only in magento2 checkout frontend and admin orders side show the all countries

How to restrict all countries except US country in magento2 checkout.

Comment: you want on checkout billing address or shipping address only?

Comment: for Shipping address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor">
    <plugin name="sr_checkout_country_list_fix"
            type="VendorName\Checkout\Plugin\Block\DirectoryDataProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

Now app/code/VendorName/Checkout/Plugin/Block/DirectoryDataProcessor.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\Checkout\Plugin\Block;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor as BaseDirectoryDataProcessor;

class DirectoryDataProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param BaseDirectoryDataProcessor $subject
     * @param $jsLayout
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        BaseDirectoryDataProcessor $subject,
        $jsLayout
    ) {
        $finalCountries = [];
        $finalCountries[] = [
            'value' => 'US',
            'label' => 'United States',
            'is_region_visible' => 1,
            'is_default' => 1
        ];

        $jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries']['country_id'] = $finalCountries;
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to restict in cart page estimate shipping and tax